# Bootstrap 3 Custom Nav li width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a container with 3 columns.

```
Logo - Nav - Search
```

What I want is my nav li elements to be forced onto two lines like so:

```
Gaming &       Home &
Technology     Garden
```

The only way I can achieve this is using width:67px on the li element. This therefore spoils the view when responsive

I'd like to avoid having to overwrite style for a view, any ideas?

/***** EDIT *****/

Should have made it clear that I intend to collapse the nav for mobile and have the li element on one line not two.

Comment: Why not just add a line break?

Comment: You could just use linebreaks...

Comment: If possible have a span tag before your text alone and style your span tag alone so that your responsive wont get affected.http://jsfiddle.net/2yo80Ldy/1/ like this

Comment: Cant linebreak as when nav collapsed, the li element would still include the line break.

Comment: Just append at the end of the li element your custom class, set it with the width that you want and just change the width to 100% for mobile.

It doesn't really change the bootstrap code, but it just ovverride that specific value. Just remember to set !important to your new width so that you're sure it will be applied.

Comment: Ok, thats what I thought, just wondered if any bootstrap properties already existed for this, thanks all.